# instantaneously or in an instant way

Tags: difference

Is "in an instant way" good to your ears?
I want to say:

> This method takes away the ability of students to think in the target language instantaneously.

Is it possible to replace the last word with "in an instant way"?
Google comes up with some results but I'm not sure whether those pages are written by the natives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Instantaneously" sounds much more natural to me than "in an instant way".

Also, "instant" isn't quite the same as "instantaneous" ([see here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42168/difference-between-instantly-and-instantaneously)), so you would want to say "in an instantaneous way," which still sounds unnatural.